# Show table if the array.length is bigger than 0

Tags: if-statement, knockout.js

I need to display a message if the array is empty, otherise I need the data displayed in the table.

Here is what I have so far (and it does not work):

```html
<div data-bind="if: interruptions().length == 0">No service interruption has been scheduled</div>

<table id="newsTbl" class="display compact table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Body</th>
            <th>Extra</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: interruptions">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: body"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: extra"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: startDate"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I add else in here?

Comment: In this instance: `<table data-bind="if: interruptions().length !== 0">`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `else` built into Knockout. You need to use another `if` that's a negation of the first `if`.

```
<div data-bind="if: interruptions().length == 0">No service interruption has been scheduled</div>

<!-- ko if: interruptions().length > 0 -->
    <table id="newsTbl" class="display compact table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover" style="width: 100%">
<!-- /ko -->
```

As of Knockout 3.3 your only other option is something like [knockout-switch-case](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case) which adds `else` functionality to Knockout.